# Value of type 'Measurement<UnitEnergy>' has no member 'formatted'

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos

I have just decided I want to make a watch app and am trying to familiarize myself with Xcode and Swift. So I decided to follow the Workout app for watchOs tutorial and the tutorial used this block of code.

```
Text(
     Measurement(
      value: 47,
      unit: UnitEnergy.kilocalories
     ).formatted(
       .measurement(
        width: .abbreviated,
        usage: .workout,
        numberFormat: .numeric(
         precision: .fractionLength(0)
        )
       )
      )
    )
```

However when I try to use this code I get the following error.

```
Value of type 'Measurement<UnitEnergy>' has no member 'formatted'
```

Im using XCode Version 12.5.1

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need Xcode 13 beta (SwiftUI 3) for this. Or use a [MeasurementFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new way style which is required **iOS 15.0**, **Xcode 13.0+** and **watchOS 8.0+**. Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement/3816389-formatted) for more

For the lower version, you can use it like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    static let var formatter: MeasurementFormatter = {
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        formatter.unitStyle = .long
        formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(Measurement(value: 47, unit: UnitEnergy.kilocalories), formatter: Self.formatter)")
    }
}
```